# ¿Cómo puedo esperar a finalizar un proceso de clonación e instalación dentro de un contenedor que creo desde un script?

Tags: bash, script, sh, contenedor

estoy creando un script bash en el que le pasas como argumento el nombre del contenedor que quieres crear. Dentro del script se instalan todas las dependencias y se clona un servidor dentro del propio contenedor.
El código del script es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Instalar LXD utilizando Snap (si no está instalado)
if ! command -v lxd &> /dev/null; then
    sudo snap install lxd
else
    echo "LXD ya está instalado."
fi

# Iniciar LXD
sudo /snap/bin/lxd init --auto

# Iniciar LXD
sudo /snap/bin/lxd init --auto

# Verificar si se puede acceder al socket de LXD
if ! /snap/bin/lxc list &> /dev/null; then
    echo "Error: No se puede acceder al socket de LXD."
    exit 1
fi

# Crear un contenedor si se proporciona un nombre como argumento
if [ "$1" ]; then
    /snap/bin/lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 "$1"
fi

# Acceder al contenedor si se proporcionó un nombre
if [ "$1" ]; then
    lxc exec "$1" -- bash -c '
        mkdir -p server &&
        cd server/ &&
        pwd &&
        git config --global --unset https.proxy &&
        git config --global --unset http.proxy &&
        git clone https://github.com/alextorsar/SSR-master-server.git &&
        cd SSR-master-server/ &&
        sudo apt-get update -y &&
        sudo apt-get upgrade -y &&
        sudo apt-get install -y npm net-tools &&
        sudo npm install -g nodemon &&
        npm install &&
        ifconfig &&
        npm start
    '
fi
```

Primero instala en el ordenador local lxd (si no lo tiene instalado) y lo inicia. Después crea el contenedor con ubuntu 20.04 y entra dentro de él para configurarlo. El problema está en que no está esperando a que finalice la clonación, por lo que cuando intenta acceder a la carpeta no puede y ya no realiza el resto de configuraciones. He comprobado que no llega a clonar la carpeta entrando manualmente al contenedor y haciendo `ls`en el directorio server.
He probado varías cosas para intentar esperar a que finalice el proceso, pero no lo consiguo. ¿Se os ocurre algo? Si sabéis cómo solucionar, por favor, comentadlo debajo.
Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: No debe esperar a que finalice la clonación?, o debe esperar a que finalice?

Comment: Buenas @Cuauhtli, me expresé mal. Efectivamente tiene que esperar a que se clone, si trata de acceder a la carpeta antes de que finalice el proceso de clonación, no encontrará la carpeta. La cosa está en cómo le digo que debe esperar a que finalice y posteriormente hacer cd a dicha carpeta

Comment: El paso del "cd" es necesario? Porque los comandos siguientes no veo que hagan uso de los programas dentro del repo clonado. Es decir, tu script quizás podría correr muy bien sin la línea del "cd".

Comment: Olvidalo, ya vi el "npm install". En ese caso, un fix rápido sería cambiar la línea del "cd" justo antes del "npm install", puesto que sólo ahí se necesita